# change value of field dynamically (OpenERP)

Tags: odoo

lets say I have a char field under osv.osv_memory

I generate a dynamic form (in "dialog" window) via the **fields_view_get** method containing this field.

During the generation of the dynamic form, how do I set the value of this field so that when the form is displayed it will contain this value (the value itself depends on the type of processing).

default_get works but only on initialization.

I can change attributes of the field such as readonly, string etc...
But the value itself need to be able to change.

Answer (score 1):

If your osv.osv_memory object is opening from osv.osv, then first create a record of osv_memory object and try to open this record in the wizard. you will not need the default_get function now to load the data to the wizard

Comment: thanks for response. will this work even if I have multiple steps, and each step has a form with different default values. because the next form is called from a method in osv.osv_memory called by a button (in the form). I will try this and get back on my results, but I'm still not quite sure how this solves my problem.